# Symfony2 get object from inverted entity with ManyToMany relation

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

I'm facing to a problem with my Doctrine entities relations.
Here's the matter :

I have 2 entities : Article and Category
Article is the master, category is the slave

I'd like to get Categories from Articles and the other way, Articles from Categories.

I made a ManyToMany relation like this :

```
class Article
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Alpha\BlogBundle\Entity\Category", cascade={"persist"}, inversedBy="Article")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="article_category")
     */
    private $categories;
```

and

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->categories = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
```

and the in Category entity :

```
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Alpha\BlogBundle\Entity\Article", cascade={"persist"}, mappedBy="Category")
     */
    private $articles;
```

and

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->articles = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
```

In my article entity, I also added the folowing :

```
public function addCategory(\Alpha\BlogBundle\Entity\Category $categories)
{
    $this->categories[] = $categories;
    $categories->addArticle($this);
    return $this;
}
```

(the forth line, `$categories->addArticle($this);`)

In my controller :

```
public function ajouterAction($data = null, $id = null) {

    // On récupère l'EM pour enregistrer en BDD
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    // On définit une nouvel objet Article avec de nouveaux attributs
    $article = new Article;
    $article->setTitle('1er article !');
    $article->setContent('Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet ice cream tiramisu unerdwear.com. Caramels halvah lollipop apple pie soufflé. Tart lollipop soufflé candy tootsie roll sweet donut. Lemon drops danish I love icing I love. Candy canes cheesecake I love. I love tiramisu applicake. I love gingerbread soufflé sweet roll muffin. Cupcake liquorice gummi bears muffin chocolate jelly-o.');
    $article->setAuthor('Toto');

    // On définit une nouvel objet Category avec de nouveaux attributs
    $category = new Category;
    $category->setName('Poney');

    $article->addCategory($category);

    $em->persist($category);
    $em->persist($article);

    $em->flush();

    return $this->render('AlphaBlogBundle:Blog:ajouter.html.twig');
}
```

And to finish, to get my articles from the categories :

```
public function categoryAction($cat = null) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    // Si cat est vide, on renvoit la liste complète des catégories
    if (!isset($cat) || empty($cat) || $cat == null) {

        $categories = $em->getRepository('AlphaBlogBundle:Category')->findAll();

        return $this->render('AlphaBlogBundle:Blog:categories.html.twig', array(
            'categories' => $categories
        ));
    }
    // Sinon on renvoit la liste des articles de la catégorie
    else {
        $category = $em->getRepository('AlphaBlogBundle:Category')->findOneBy(array('name' => $cat));
        $articles = $category->getArticles();

        return $this->render('AlphaBlogBundle:Blog:category.html.twig', array(
            'articles' => $articles,
            'category' => $category
            //'name' => $name
        ));
    }
}
```

In my view, I can see the name of my category, but the article is not showing, I have this error message :

`ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined index: Category in /home/franck/www/alpha/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 1036`

I'm a bit lost here, if someone could help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As follows from [doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytomany):

> mappedBy: This option specifies the property name on the targetEntity
>   that is the owning side of this relation. Its a required attribute for
>   the inverse side of a relationship.
>
> inversedBy: The inversedBy attribute designates the ﬁeld in the entity
>   that is the inverse side of the relationship.

So, try to change `inversedBy="Article"` to `inversedBy="articles"` in Article class and `mappedBy="Category"` to `mappedBy="categories"` in Category class.

Also see [this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional) Many-To-Many bidirectional example.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

All right then, I followed your advice and changed Article with articles, and Category by categories. I also changed my mapping for the master side, Articles, like that :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(
 *    targetEntity="Alpha\BlogBundle\Entity\Category",
 *    cascade={"persist"},
 *    inversedBy="articles"
 * )
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="article_category",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={
 *          @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *      }
 * )
 */
```

It works like a charm. I don't exactly understand but I'm gonna study that :)